# What does Managed="0" in List view XML mean?

Tags: tridion

I've written a Data Extender class and editor extension that properly displays a few additional columns for items as you browse lists in the CME (folders and structure groups). I had to register my class to handle commands like GetList, GetListSearch, GetListUserFavorites, and GetListCheckedOutItems.

What I've noticed is that the code gets run even when a list of say, schemas is loaded for a drop-down list in the CME (like when creating a new component and you get the list of schemas in a drop-down). so, even though my additional data columns aren't needed in that situation, the code is still being executed and it slows things down.

It seems that it's the GetList command called in those situations. So, I can't just skip processing based on the command. So, I started looking at the XML that the class receives for the list and I've noticed when the code is run for the drop-downs, there's a `Managed="0"` in the XML. For example:

- For a Structure Group list: `<tcm:ListItems Managed="64" ID="tcm:103-546-4">`
- For a Folder list: `<tcm:ListItems Managed="16" ID="tcm:103-411-2">`
- But for a Schema list: `<tcm:ListItems ID="tcm:0-103-1" Managed="0">`
- For a drop-down showing keyword values for a category: `<tcm:ListItems Managed="0" ID="tcm:103-506-512">`

So, can I just use this Managed="0" as a flag to indicate that the list being processed isn't going to show my additional columns and I can just quit processing?

Comment: thanks for the clean up Frank!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Managed` value is representation of what items can be created inside `OrganizationItem`:

- 64 means you can create pages
- 16 means you can create components
- 10, for example would mean you can create folders (2) + schemas (8)
- 518 - folders (2) + structure groups (4) + categories (512)

The value is 0 for non organizational items.

Value depends on the item itself (you can't create pages in folder, for example), as well as on security settings you have on publication and organizational item

Comment: Thanks for that explanation Andrey. But shouldn't the Category in Warner's case then say that he can create Keywords (assuming he has sufficient rights)?

Comment: I think that would only happen if the view calling it is the Category itself, I think this is the XML returned when you get a list of keyword for creating a component. In that case you would not be able to make keywords there

Comment: Thanks all. this is very educational. clearly this doesn't help in what I was trying to accomplish. but it's good to know what it can be used for should I need it.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately CME can't offer right now that kind of granularity level to allow you to tell in a data extender where a particular WCF API call is coming from. Our WCF API is not context aware yet. It may change in the future.

Trusting Managed="0" is not a great idea.
The reason for that is the model lists are client cached per filter. In the current design the filter has CM related data and nothing related to the context the request is being fired from.
Typically the client user interface is reusing cached model data whenever is possible. For instance the same model list could be used in the CME dashboard and a drop down control placed into some item view, but with different xml list definitions: the first one will have more columns defined in the list definition than the latter. They are basically different views of the same data.

Therefore you may want to think of different solutions for your problem.
Now... where is the data behind those additional columns is coming from? Is it Tridion CM or a third party provider?
Sometimes the web server caching may provide an acceptable way to improve the response times. But that's the kind of design you should evaluate and decide upon.

Comment: Thanks! I submitted an enhancement request to make it possible to tell the origin of the GetList command. for our specific implementation, all the data comes from Tridion CM so caching isn't really appropriate. the columns we've added are: Modified By, Version, Approval Status, Locked By, Publish Date. What I'd some day love to be able to do is give content authors the ability to set a preference to turn the additional columns on or off as needed. turning them off would obviously speed up their navigation in the CME, turning it on would allow them to see this other information they need.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would have a more robust solution if you read the ID of the list, and only execute your code for lists of type 2 and 4 (Folders and Structure Groups respectively). but that won't help you with search views etc.

Comment: It seems to be the one of the more common approaches I've seen: find ways to identify lists you don't want to process and `if` those. Even if you can't get all of them in one go, you'll slowly make things faster with a manageable amount of risk per iteration. Between that and an aggressive caching strategy for the information you are adding, you can typically get things reasonably performant. Of course, nothing beats the performance of ***not*** adding custom columns to the list. So you should always consider that option first... and last.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: completely agree. however, battle fought and lost (for now). these numerous additional columns are considered essential for business purposes.

Answer (score 2):

From previous experience and what User978511 says the `Managed` attribute is an indication of item types that can be created from the context of that list.

Unfortunately that means that the `Managed` attribute may well be 0 for any user that doesn't have sufficient rights to create items. E.g. check what `Managed` is in a Structure Group for a user that isn't allowed to create Pages or Structure Groups. It may well be `0` in that case too, meaning it is useless for your situation.

***Update***

You may be able to reach your goal better by looking at the `columns` parameter:

```
context.Parameters["columns"]
```

In a few tests I've run I get different values, depending on whether I get a list for the main list view, the tree or a drop down list.

```
543
 23
  7
```

Those values are a bit mask of these constants (from `Constants.js`):

```js
/**
 * Defines the column filter.
 * Used to specify which attributes should be included in XML list data.
 * @enum
 */
Tridion.Constants.ColumnFilter =
{
    ID: 1,
    ID_AND_TITLE: 3,
    DEFAULT: 7,
    EXTENDED: 15,
    ALLOWED_ACTIONS: 16,
    VERSIONS: 32,
    INTERNALS: 64,
    URL: 128,
    XML_NAME: 256,
    CHECK_OUT_USER: 512,
    PUBTITLE_AND_ITEM_PATH: 1024
};
```

So from my limited testing it seems that drop downs request `DEFAULT` columns, while the main list view and the tree both have `ALLOWED_ACTIONS` in there. This makes sense to me, since the user gets can interact with the list items in the tree and list view, while they can only select them in the drop downs. So checking for the presence of `ALLOWED_ACTIONS` in the `columns` parameter might be one way to reduce the number of places where your data extender adds information.

Comment: I'll try to experiment with that and see if I disable a user's permissions if that changes that value. Different question. is there something else I can use in a Data Extender (perhaps the PipelineContext) to detect what "kind" of GetList command is being executed? It would be handy if there were other commands for those cases so we could distinguish what type of list was being processed.

Comment: There is a fine balance between allowing your code to detect the exact place where it is called from and optimizing the caching for the fact that many such places retrieve the exact same data. I am not even sure if a GetList call for a dropdown should be different from one for a list view. Or at the very least: once you've shown the keywords in the list, there is not need to call the server to get the data for a dropdown; it is just a subset of what was already retrieved.

Comment: You might want to look at the filters that get passed into your DataExtender in `pipelineContext.Parameters["filter"]`. The `ItemTypes` in the filter seem to also give some indication of the context of the request.

Comment: I looked at the Filter from the pipelineContext and it was null. I tried inspecting what else pipelineContext gives. I see a key of "command:type" which appears to be of type "Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Lists" any idea what that is and what it would tell me?